# When I install my app, Anti-Virus tells me that this program is harmful

Tags: android, android-service

When I install my app, Anti-Virus tells me that this program is harmful.
I write program that run sound in back ground in specific time interval , here is my code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    boolean check_service;
    int time = 59995;
    Calendar calendar;
    AlarmManager alarms;
    PendingIntent recurringLl24;
    Switch mySwitch;
    String item;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();

        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        // final Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        check_service = isMyServiceRunning(LifeLogService.class);
        if (check_service == true) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);


        }

        ////////////////////////
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent ll24 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, AlarmReceiverLifeLog.class);
        recurringLl24 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main2Activity.this, 0, ll24, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");


                    try {
                        switch (time) {
                            case 59995:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 599995, recurringLl24); // Log repetition
                                //  writeToFile(item,this);
                                break;
                            case 1799995:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, recurringLl24); // Log repetition

                                break;
                            case 3599995:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, recurringLl24); // Log repetition

                                break;
                            case 7199995:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 7199995, recurringLl24); // Log repetition

                                break;
                            case 90000:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 90000, recurringLl24); // Log repetition

                                break;
                            case 2700000:
                                alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 2700000, recurringLl24); // Log repetition

                                break;

                        }
                        // alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "بدا التسبيح ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //mySwitch.setChecked(true);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                } else {
                    try {

                        //stopService(i);
                        alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "توقف التسبيح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
// On selecting a spinner item
        item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        switch (item) {
            case "10 MIN":
                time = 59995;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "توقف التسبيح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case "30 MIN":
                time = 1799995;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "توقف التسبيح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case "Hour":
                time = 3599995;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "توقف التسبيح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case "2 Hour":
                time = 7199995;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "توقف التسبيح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case "15 MIN":
                time = 900000;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case "45 MIN":
                time = 2700000;
                alarms.cancel(recurringLl24);
                mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                break;

        }
        // Showing selected spinner item
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }




}
```

my service is

```
public class LifeLogService extends Service {
    public LifeLogService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    MediaPlayer objPlayer;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int notificationID = 100;
    private int numMessages = 0;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        /* Invoking the default notification service */
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("تسبيحه جديده");
        mBuilder.setContentText("سبحان الله والحمد لله ولا اله الا الله");
        mBuilder.setTicker("سبحان الله والحمد لله ولا اله الا الله");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ac);
        /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
        mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);



        /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationView.class);

        /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


        ////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////

        objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sphan_allah);
        Runnable r=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                {synchronized (this){
                    try {
                        //wakeLock.acquire();
                        objPlayer.start();
                        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                          /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
                        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }
            }

        };

        Thread bucky=new Thread(r);
        bucky.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

my BroadcastReceiver is

```
public class AlarmReceiverLifeLog extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AlarmReceiverLifeLog() {
    }

    private static final String TAG = "LL24";
    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Alarm for LifeLog...");
        Intent ll24Service = new Intent(context, LifeLogService.class);
        context.startService(ll24Service);
    }
}
```

and my NotificationView is :

```
public class NotificationView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_view);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add exception to anti-virus about this exe.

Comment: its an android  program (APK) ,

Comment: It's a false positive. You should get rid the anti-virus 1 years ago